# Linking a framework depending on 'Build' or 'Debug' mode in Xcode5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks, xcode5

I am building a Mac app using Xcode5 on 10.9.2. My project uses a third party framework -- for the sake of simplicity, let's call it XYZ.framework.

There are two versions of XYZ.framework provided: a debug version and a release version. The debug version of the framework is considerably larger, but it carries important functionality for debugging like printing warnings to the console, asserts, etc. The release version of the framework is smaller, faster, and is intended for production. The debug version resides at debug/XYZ.framework and the release version resides at release/XYZ.framework.

**My question is: How do I include the correct version of the framework depending on my build configuration?** I.E., Xcode should include debug/XYZ.framework when my build configuration is Debug, or include release/XYZ.framework when my build configuration is Release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is,create separate folder to keep the debug version of framework and release version of framework. Next step specify the framework search path according to build configuration. Below is the steps to customise framework search path:

1. Go to build settings.
2. Search for "framework search paths" in build settings.
3. Edit framework search path according to your configuration.

Additionally this [thread may also help you.](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/246608-linking-debug-release-app-with-debug-release-framework.html)

Comment: I also needed to add a step in Fastlane to write over the development version of the framework with the release version and do not include the release version in any targets. Otherwise Apple rejects the release

Comment: The link in this answer no longer works.

Comment: Is the instructions the same for XCFramework? I added an XCFramework in my project, but I couldn't find it under framework search paths.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate build target for your debug app:

```
Target > Debug.app
```

Under Build Phases:

**Link Binary with Libraries**:

```
Click + Then Add Your Debugging Framework
Remove the Release one by clicking -
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will mean I have to maintain two targets from now on. Xcode already has support for a Debug and Release build baked in, so I shouldn't have to make a whole separate target just for this purpose.

Comment: @jerzy, The Debug Build options can be defined however you want under schemes. When you include a different library in debug vs release then your target is essentially not the same. If you don't want another target then create a build script to isolate the frameworks during the build phase by the criteria you define.